# Recursive function with boolean operators

Tags: java, recursion

Hello I was wondering if someone could help walk me through what happens when I have a couple of recursive calls involving a boolean operator?
So for example how would this code run?

```
boolean covers(TreeNode root, TreeNode p) {
  if(root == null) return false;
  if(root == p) return true;
  return covers(root.left, p) || covers(root.right, p); //this is what confuses me 
}
```

For context TreeNode root is the root of the Btree and TreeNode p is a node in the Btree.

Comment: If none are `null`, it will execute `covers(root.left,p)`, then based on the result, as you have `||`, will execute `covers(root.right,p)` if needed . As the walkthrough, use a debugger or add some log to follow the code.

Comment: the line `return covers(root.left, p) || covers(root.right, p);` will return true if either of the statements are true

Comment: i think the most easy way to adress this is using the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're searching with in a tree, for example:

```
  a    
 / \   
b   c
```

Imagine that we're interested in finding out if the node c is under (covered) by a.

Unpacking the method:

```
boolean covers(TreeNode root, TreeNode p) { // does root, cover the node p
  if(root == null) return false; // if null no
  if(root == p) return true; // if root == p then yes
  return covers(root.left, p) || covers(root.right, p); // if i'm not not p, could one of my children be p
}
```

Because this is recursive, we continue the method again, this time with the root as the left child. This results in a depth first search, with the first right node being evaluated when we've run out of left nodes to test. 
Note that if : covers(root.left, p) - returns true, then covers(root.right, p) is never evaluated.

```
    a    
   / \   
  b   c
 / \
d  e
```

In our example, if we were searching for node c. We would recurse like so :

```
covers(a, c)
  covers(b, c)
    covers(d, c)
    covers(e, c)
  covers(c, c) <- returns true
```

Comment: This is a good explanation, but you should add one more level to this tree, to show that it will evaluate every nodes of `b` (left from right) before checking `c` (as explained verbaly). An example is always a plus ;)

Answer (score 0):

return covers(root.left, p) || covers(root.right, p);

This line will return true if either of functions' return is true (because of ||).

Function will return true if node == p otherwise they will reach at leaf and become null and will return false.

Answer (score 0):

The code will first check if `root` is `null`. If so, the element `p` cannot be covered, so the return value is `false`.

After that, the code will check if the elements are equal. So `p` is covered by `root`, if it is equal to `root`. So `true` is returned.

Otherwise, p must be covered by the left or the right child. So you can use the `covers()` function again (recursive) to check that.

The first term of the last line (`covers(root.left, p)`) checks if `p` is covered by the left child, the second term (`covers(root.right, p)`) checks if `p` is covered by the right child. The OR operator (`||`) combines the function calls and returns `true` if one (or both) function call returned `true`.

Answer (score 0):

The program will first evaluate `covers(root.left, p)`. Then:

1. If `covers(root.left, p)` is `true`, the whole expression will evaluate to `true`. You're using an OR and since one of the conditions is `true`, `covers(root.right, p)` will NOT need to be evaluated.
2. If `covers(root.left, p)` is `false`, the program will need to evaluate `covers(root.right, p)` to determine the result of the expression.

Here's something (in pseudocode) you can play with to understand this:

```
function doSomething() {
  log 'hello world!'
};

x = false || doSomething(); // doSomething will be executed
x = true || doSomething(); // doSomething will NOT be executed
```

Answer (score 0):

simply this line the quarantee of visiting all nodes in btree.

```
 covers(root.left, p) || covers(root.right, p)
```